# Cannot read property 'type' of undefined on webrtc peer to peer connection

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, webrtc

I have an issue on webrtc peer to peer video chat, I am able to connect to peers in video call, but I have this error in my console. (refer to the screenshot below), there are a lot of it that errors and I cant find which one causes it as it randomly occurs during the process of creating the connection.

[image]

Comment: search your code for something.type - something is undefined

Comment: hard to tell with no code examples